# Setting up WAMP Server Names for local development

Tags: wamp

I'm used to using MAMP for web development, and one of the things I can easily do is setup a new host for each project so that `http://localhost/project1` can be accessed from `http://project1`.

How can I do the same on WAMP? Because my projects often have .htaccess rules set for URL rewriting or any paths that reference to the root, `http://localhost/project1` blows up in WAMP for testing purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do two things for this to work.

1. Set up a host name alias on your system. On pretty much any modern version of Windows, this is done through the file `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. Find the line that starts with `127.0.0.1` and append whatever hostname you like to it (multiple hostnames are separated by spaces). I'd suggest using something `.local` to make sure it doesn't clash with any registered DNS name. (`.local` isn't officially reserved, but I can't imagine it'll ever be a valid TLD.)
2. Add a name-based virtual host to your Apache installation, using the name you created above. I'm pretty sure there's a tool included with WAMP to do this, but I don't recall the exact steps involved and don't have easy access to a WAMP installation right now.

When this is done, you should be able to access `http://your-chosen-host-name.local`.